# About uml class diagram, how to put array as attribute

Tags: uml, class-diagram

What I would like to ask is that if one class has a variable of array, should I include it as attribute along with the association or only the association?

So, for example, if I want to draw a simple diagram about association between professor and lecture, which side would be correct (Upper one or the lower one)?
- Lecture may have more than one instructor

[image]

Comment: you have a many-to-many relationship here, you better think of using an [association class](http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Association+Class/)

Comment: @RisingSilver Many-to-many does not necessarily mean association class.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I didn't say that it does, I just suggested it.

Comment: @ElSam Sound's like you're in the advertisement business xD And you're still free to implement it as AC (which you would do when using it in a database) even if not explicitly written as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the dot notation with role names like this:

[image]

It means that `Professor` has `*` `lectures` as owned property and vice versa `Lecture` has `1..*` `teachers`.

The dot and role name are located "on the opposite site" of the owning class.